# Finding efficiently common greatest common divisor for a list of large numbers

Tags: algorithm, numbers, primes

I have a task for which I need to check whether a list of numbers can be simplified using a common divisor.

for example, if we have numbers 12 48 36, they all are divisible by 12. I have tried using prime number factorization . However, some of the numbers I have are really large (say 2 billion) and finding all possible prime divisors quickly becomes infeasible. For the example above prime number factorization works nicely:

```
12=2^2*3
48=2^4*3
36=2^2*3^2
```

I have tried running Eclidean algorithm ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm ) for each pair and taking the smallest number but I am not sure such an approach is valid and will not hit some edge case where the results are valid.

example:

```
min(gcd(12,48), gcd(48,36), gcd(36,12))
```

So my question is what is the most computationally efficient method to find the least common denominator/divisor for a list of numbers, especially if the numbers tend to be large?

Comment: Minor discrepancy: Your title mentions GCD, the body of your post says LCD. You may want to fix that for clarity.

Comment: `gcd(a,b,c) = gcd( a, gcd(b,c))` will works

Comment: so my approach is wrong to try to get simply the smallest gcd from all pairs... Is there an efficient way to do the permutations of the numbers?

Comment: You do not need to do all the permutations since `gcd(a, b) = gcd(b, a)` and this also apply for `n` numbers. Just do this for all of the numbers and you are done.

Comment: To be pedandic: gcd operation is commutative and associative

Comment: btw why nobody submitted an answer , while the comments are almost there?